# 2D CNN to classify 3D Greyscale MRI data, possible data labeling issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mri, medical-imaging

I am trying to run a binary classification of 3D black and white MRI data. I'm using 2D convolutions due to the lack of channels inherent in B&W data. I've added a dimension to get the dimensionality to line up, and essentially the depth of this data is acting as the batch dimension. I am using a subsample of data, 20 files each 189 by 233 by 197. Just as a quick background.

I have a csv file with a bunch of info including the label data for each file which I've tried to extract, as per the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import glob

import SimpleITK as sitk

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.utils import np_utils

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

datapath = ('/content/gdrive/My Drive/DirectoryTest/All Data/')
patients = os.listdir(datapath)
labels_df = pd.read_csv('/content/Data_Index.csv', index_col = 0 )

labelset = []

for i in patients:
  label = labels_df.loc[i, 'Group']
  if label is 'AD':
    np.char.replace(label, ['AD'], [0])
  if label is 'CN':
    np.char.replace(label, ['CN'], [1])
  labelset.append(label)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
labelset = label_encoder.fit_transform(labelset)

labelset = np_utils.to_categorical(labelset, num_classes= 2)

FullDataSet = []

for i in patients:
  a = sitk.ReadImage(datapath + i)
  b = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(a)
  c = np.reshape(b, (189,233,197, 1))
  FullDataSet.append(c)

training_data, testing_data, training_labels, testing_labels = train_test_split(FullDataSet, labelset, train_size=0.70,test_size=0.30)

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((training_data, training_labels))
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testing_data, testing_labels))

CNN_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
  [
      #tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(189, 233, 197, 1), batch_size=2),
      #tf.keras.layers.Reshape((197, 233, 189, 1)),   
                              
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(7, 7), data_format='channels_last', filters=64, activation='relu',
                             padding='same', strides=( 3, 3), input_shape=( 233, 197, 1)),
      #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=False),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
      
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=( 7, 7), filters=128, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=( 3, 3)),
      #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=False),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), padding='same'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),      

      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=( 7, 7), filters=256, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=( 3, 3)),
      #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=False),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), padding = 'same'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20), 

      # last activation could be either sigmoid or softmax, need to look into this more. Sig for binary output, Soft for multi output 
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),   
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')

  ])
# Compile the model
CNN_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# print model layers
CNN_model.summary()

CNN_history = CNN_model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=10, validation_data=dataset_test)
```

When I go to fit the model I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a8b210ec2e72> in <module>()
      1 #running of the model
      2 #CNN_history = CNN_model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=100, validation_data =dataset_test, validation_steps=1)
----> 3 CNN_history = CNN_model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=10, validation_data=dataset_test)
      4 
      5 

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:749 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1605 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4829 binary_crossentropy
        bce = target * math_ops.log(output + epsilon())
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1141 binary_op_wrapper
        raise e
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1125 binary_op_wrapper
        return func(x, y, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:1457 _mul_dispatch
        return multiply(x, y, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:509 multiply
        return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:6176 mul
        "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:744 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:593 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3485 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1975 __init__
        control_input_ops, op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1815 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 189 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](ExpandDims, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [2,1], [189,2].
```

I know the 2 in [189,2] is associated with the final softmax layer but I don't know what to do with that information, or where to go from here.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some comments regarding your code, hopefully helpful.

## Use `Conv3D` and `MaxPool3D`

If you're dealing with 3D images, then you should almost certainly use [`Conv3D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3D) instead of `Conv2D`, and [`MaxPool3D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MaxPool3D) instead of `MaxPool2D`. Here's an example (using random data), which I just tested, and it seems to work fine:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

train_size = 20
val_size = 5

X_train = np.random.random([train_size, 189, 233, 197]).astype(np.float32)
X_valid = np.random.random([val_size, 189, 233, 197]).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=train_size).astype(np.float32)
y_valid = np.random.randint(2, size=val_size).astype(np.float32)

CNN_model = keras.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Reshape([189, 233, 197, 1], input_shape=[189, 233, 197]),
      keras.layers.Conv3D(kernel_size=(7, 7, 7), filters=32, activation='relu',
                          padding='same', strides=(3, 3, 3)),
      #keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'),
      keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
      
      keras.layers.Conv3D(kernel_size=(5, 5, 5), filters=64, activation='relu',
                          padding='same', strides=(3, 3, 3)),
      #keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'),
      keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),

      keras.layers.Conv3D(kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), filters=128, activation='relu',
                          padding='same', strides=(1, 1, 1)),
      #keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      keras.layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'),
      keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),

      keras.layers.Flatten(),
      keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),   
      keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
      keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
  ])

# Compile the model
CNN_model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001),
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# print model layers
CNN_model.summary()

CNN_history = CNN_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,
                            validation_data=[X_valid, y_valid])
```

## Don't reshape to permute dimensions

Regarding these two commented out lines:

```py
      #tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(189, 233, 197, 1), batch_size=2),
      #tf.keras.layers.Reshape((197, 233, 189, 1)),
```

Reshaping a 189x233x197x1 image to 197x233x189x1 will not work as you expect. It will completely shuffle the pixels around, making the task much harder. This is similar to reshaping a 2x3 image into a 3x2 image:

```
>>> img = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> np.reshape(img, [3, 2])
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Notice that this is *not* the same as rotating the image: the pixels are completely mixed up.

What you want is to use [`tf.keras.layers.Permute()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Permute) instead like this:

```py
CNN_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Permute((3, 2, 1, 4), input_shape=(189, 233, 197, 1)),
      ...
])
```

Because these commented out lines were wrong, I suspect that the following line may also be wrong:

```py
c = np.reshape(b, (189,233,197, 1))
```

I don't know the shape of `b`, so please make absolutely sure that it is compatible with this `np.reshape()` operation. For example, if its shape is `[189, 233, 197]`, that's fine. But if it is `[197, 233, 189]`, for example, then you will need to permute dimensions before you reshape:

```py
b_permuted = np.transpose(b, [2, 1, 0]) # permute dims
c = np.reshape(b_permuted, [189, 233, 197, 1]) # then add the channels dim
```

The [`np.transpose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) function is similar to using `Permute()`, except dimensions are 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed.

It may be even more complex. For example, if the 3D images are stored as large 2D images containing smaller 2D slices side by side, then the shape of `b` may be something like `[189*197, 233]`. In this case, you would need to do something like this:

```py
b_reshaped = np.reshape(b, [189, 197, 233, 1])
c = np.transpose(b_reshaped, [0, 2, 1, 3])
```

I hope these examples are clear enough.

## Use `tf.keras`, not `keras`

There are several implementations of the Keras API. One is the `keras` package, which is the "multi-backend" Keras (which is installed using `pip install keras`). Another is `tf.keras` and it comes with TensorFlow. Your program seems to use both. You should absolutely avoid that, it will cause weird issues.

```py
from keras.utils import plot_model # this is multibackend Keras
...
CNN_model = tf.keras.Sequential(...) # this is tf.keras
```

I highly recommend you uninstall multibackend keras, to avoid this type of error: `pip uninstall keras`. Then fix the imports by prefixing with `tensorflow.`, for example:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical # note: not from np_utils
...
```

## Don't use `to_categorical()` for binary classification

For binary classification, the labels should simply be a 1D array containing 0s and 1s, such as `np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 1.])`. The code can be quite simplified:

```py
labelset = []

for i in patients:
  label = labels_df.loc[i, 'Group']
  if label == 'AD':  # use `==` instead of `is` to compare strings
    labelset.append(0.)
  elif label == 'CN':
    labelset.append(1.)
  else:
      raise "Oops, unknown label" # I recommend testing possible failure cases

labelset = np.array(labelset)
```

Importantly, for binary classification, you should use a single neuron in the output layer, and also use the `"sigmoid"` activation function (not `"softmax"`, which is used for multiclass classification):

```py
CNN_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      ...
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

## Minor comment

- You don't need to specify both the `train_size` and the `test_size` when calling `train_test_split()`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks MiniQuark, obviously I'm new to this so any pointers are appreciated. Your input shape is [train_size, 189, 233, 197], and then you reshape to add the 1 dimension. I reshape the data based on your instruction and the resulting shape is
  
[ 20, 189, 233, 197,   1]

my label data shape is

[20]

When i go to fit the model I get an error:

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189
  y sizes: 15
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.

Comment: My pleasure. :) The problem is probably that you're passing model.fit() a Python list containing 20 numpy arrays of shape [189, 233, 197, 1] rather than a single NumPy array of shape [20, 189, 233, 197, 1]. This can be fixed by executing: FullDataSet = np.stack(FullDataSet) just before calling train_test_split(). Note: if you already have the channels dimension (of size 1), then you don't need the Reshape layer in my example. Hope this helps.